# Losing connection on Geth websocket subscription

Tags: go-ethereum, python, websocket

I am trying to keep multiple WebSocket connections to my Geth node open at the same time (around 200 connections). My issue is that they keep closing with a timeout error. I can't seem to know if it's just that there is no data to return for the duration of the timeout or that they just disconnected.

I am doing it in Python, listening for the logs of a contract :

```
        async with connect(self.webSocket_provider) as ws:
            await ws.send(json.dumps(.....))
            subscription_response = await ws.recv()
            print(f"WebSocket Connection open")
            self.websocketConnectionOpen = True
            while True:
                try:
                    message = await asyncio.wait_for(ws.recv(), timeout=90)
                    stTime = time.time()
                    decoded = decode_single('(uint112,uint112)',
                                            bytearray.fromhex(json.loads(message)['params']['result']['data'][2:]))
                except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                    await ws.close()
                    # No data in 20 seconds, check the connection.
                    try:
                        pong_waiter = await ws.ping()
                        await asyncio.wait_for(pong_waiter, timeout=10)
                    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                        # No response to ping in 10 seconds, disconnect.
                        break
                except Exception as E:
                    await ws.close()
                    raise E
```

After the websocket `recV()` reaches the timeout it tries to ping the gethNode, if not it means the gethNode has disconnected. My issue is that the ping never succeeds at resuming the connection, it always ends up with the connection closing. So my question is whether geth actually respond to pings or not. If so, how can i keep the connection open without resorting to the pings after the initial timeOut?

The errors I get are :

```
    code = 1000 (OK), no reason
    code = 1006 (connection closed abnormally [internal]), no reason
```

Comment: Were you able to find the issue?

Comment: @Undead8 no, not really. but I think it's a geth problem. using web3Js was easier as  you can specify the automatic keepAlive duration and whether to reconnect automatically on disconnection, which worked better than this (with web3.py)